# I'm Trying to get all button id's from a parent container and always get the last one

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, for-loop

I am trying to get a list of all ids from children from a parent container and I keep getting the last id only.  How can I get an array or string with all Ids?  These buttons will be dynamically created by PHP so I won't actually know what id will be there.

```js
var childDivs = document.getElementById('onlineDrop').getElementsByTagName('button');
for (var i = 0; i < childDivs.length; i++) { 
childDiv = childDivs[i].id;
}
alert(childDiv);
```

```html
<div id="onlineDrop">
<button id="222222"></button>
<button id="333333"></button>
<button id="444444"></button>
</div>
```

No Jquery please.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Barmar's solution looks good, to create an array of the ids. Just as an extra thing, are trying to add event listeners to these buttons dynamically? I had a similar project years ago (with vanilla JS and php) and had trouble with adding listeners to the buttons as It was adding it to the last button only. I found a solution. If you need help with this let me know..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the IDs to an array.

```js
var childDivs = document.getElementById('onlineDrop').getElementsByTagName('button');
childIds = [];

for (var i = 0; i < childDivs.length; i++) {
  childIds.push(childDivs[i].id);
}
console.log(childIds);
```

```html
<div id="onlineDrop">
  <button id="222222"></button>
  <button id="333333"></button>
  <button id="444444"></button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you that is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach for this could be using [Array.from()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) method of arrays:

```js
var childDivs = document.getElementById('onlineDrop').getElementsByTagName('button');

let ids = Array.from({length: childDivs.length}, (v, i) => childDivs[[i]].id);

console.log(ids);
```

```html
<div id="onlineDrop">
<button id="222222">B1</button>
<button id="333333">B2</button>
<button id="444444">B3</button>
</div>
```